# Spring transaction JMS+ MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-transactions

I am planning on using the Mybatis as the ORM tool for my application, before I dive deep into the configuration, i'd like to know if there is a way I can do JMS + Mybatis into the same transaction(Like XA transaction or two phase commit)? If not, does spring JDBC support the above case?

I've looked up a few answers in the SO, but have not got a concrete answer to Mybatis related.

Referred:

[Spring Transaction Synchonization of JDBC and JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229573/spring-transaction-synchonization-of-jdbc-and-jms)

[IBM MQManager as XA Transaction Manager with Spring-jms and Spring-tx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957045/ibm-mqmanager-as-xa-transaction-manager-with-spring-jms-and-spring-tx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it must be. I have experience with hibernate and JMS(spring-jms) but not with JMS and mybatis. But here is some code example that could help in your case.

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    .....
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>
```

This sorts out JTA participation for JMS. Read [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/239455?_sscc=t) for Mybatis inclusion in JTA transaction.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/DBDS"/>

<bean id="myBatisSqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">    
 ....
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
  <property name="transactionFactory">  
  <bean class="org.apache.ibatis.transaction.managed.ManagedTransactionFactory" />  
  </property>
</bean>
```